# How do I specify "%-*s" in new-style .format()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I would like to translate the following code

```
print "%-*s" % (10, 'foo')
```

which would print `foo` with 7 trailing spaces (field width == 10, left justified), into a Python 3 `.format()` call, but not having much luck googling.. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'{1:{0}}'.format(10, 'foo')
```

or with implicit indices:

```
'{:{}}'.format('foo', 10)
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Comment: Why `{1:{0}}` in the first one and not `{0:{1}}` (so the argument order would stay the same)?

Comment: So that the argument order would stay the same (w/r/t your previous solution with operator `%`)

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
'{:<10}'.format('foo')
```

Comment: This puts leading spaces, not trailing.

Comment: Edited to trailing spaces. For leading spaces use `'{:>10}'.format('foo')` in stead.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```python
"{:<10}".format("foo")
```

Which will produce (spaces replaced by underscores):

> 'foo_______'

For more information check out the section [Format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) of the python documentation.

Comment: @thebjorn Indeed, however not doing so was not stated as a requirement. If this is required, use Kos' solution (i.e. nested formatting strings).

Comment: technically that is true, and that is the best kind of truth... (otoh, the `*` in the format string could have been a clue.. :-)